# UITableView checkmark in some particular row in every section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` containing 'N' number of sections with 'N' no of rows in each section.

My requirement is:

When the table view page loads the 1st row in each section must be check-marked. The user then will have the option to select his choice in each section and that row in that particular section is check-marked.

How do I implement this functionality?

Comment: How have you tried doing it? What data is used to fill your table view now?

Comment: My tableview will contain different filter options and each section the filter criteria is diffrent.

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this

Answer (score 1):

The information displayed in any particular row of a table is determined by the table's data source. Make sure that the data structure that you use for your data has some way of indicating that a given row has a check mark. Then just implement `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` such that it determines whether a check mark should be displayed for the cell in question and adjusts the cell accordingly.

For example, let's say that the data is represented as an array of sections, and each section is an array of dictionaries. Each row, then, has its own dictionary. If a row is to have a check mark, its dictionary will have a `checked` entry set to `YES`; if it doesn't, that entry is `NO`. You can display the check mark as an image. Then you have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = ... // code to get the cell

    if (myData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"checked"].boolValue == YES) {
        cell.checkedImageView.image = self.checkmarkImage;
    }
    else {
        cell.checkedImageView.image = nil;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Putting the check mark in the first row of each section is just a matter of initializing your data so that the first entry in each section's array is checked and the others aren't.

You can change the checked cell by implementing `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` so that it scans through the array for the given section and unchecks any checked row, and then checks the selected row.

Of course, you don't have to represent your data using an array of arrays of dictionaries, and there's a good chance that you don't. That's fine -- the point here is just that you'll implement the functionality that you're after by implementing the table's delegate and data source such that they support the check mark, and that the presence or absence of the check mark in any particular row will be determined by some aspect of your table's data.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your cell's accessoryType to a checkmark:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ... // code to get the cell

    // isCellSelectedAtIndexPath: is your custom method
    // which encapsulates cell selection state logic
    if ([self isCellSelectedAtIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does the custom method isCellSelectedAtIndexPath actually contain ?

Comment: +1 Good point. @user2552714, that method presumably contains the code that determines whether the cell should have the check mark. Again, your data source will need to make the decision based on whatever data it's using to populate the table.

Comment: I did not understand your second sentence. Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: @user2552714, regarding isCellSelectedAtIndexPath, the method name is simply an example and the assumption is you would have it defined elsewhere in the class. It contains the logic you use to determine if a cell should be selected.

Comment: -(BOOL)isCellSelectedAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexpath          { if (indexpath.row==0) return YES else return NO    } I have written this

Comment: By the above code, am able to checkmark 1st row of every section.But when I click on other rows the checkmark is not updated

Comment: That's a separate question, and a different protocol: UITableViewDelegate